# figure on scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gre-exam

[image]

generally it is well known  that angle inscribed  by  diameter is $90$,but because on GRE figures are   not  drawn on scale,that why i want to make sure that  my assumption about $y$ is $90$ ,generally  in some problem,it is always possible to redraw   figures so that create different  angles and different  form,that why i want to be sure that if such kind of figure would be on GRE, i would not make any mistake,,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed, $y = 90^\circ$, since you are *given* that the angle is inscribed by the *diameter.* And you note, this is a fairly well know theorem. That is, by [Thales Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Thales%27_Theorem), we know that $y = 90^\circ$.

So in this case, you can rest assured you are given all the information you need, drawn to scale or not.

Answer (score 2):

The angle at the perimeter is half the angle at the centre.

So, the angle at the centre is $180$, and the angle at the perimeter is $90$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the given chord is said to be diameter use the property :

> Angle in a semicircle is a right angle $90 ^\circ $

ref : http://www.mathopenref.com/semiinscribed.html